# Limited flash memory of ESP32 way below declared 4mb for SPIFFS

Tags: esp32, spiffs

I'm using ESP32 module WEMOS LOLIN32 to setup simple webserver with basic captive portal.
I've modyfied build-in example of Captive Portal to work as async web server, with all files stored as SPIFFS. All is working good, but I have a problem that I can't upload more then around 1 mb of files. If data folder is bigger, then I have an error:

```
SPIFFS_write error(-10001): File system is full.

error adding file!

SPIFFS Create Failed!
```

I don't know if flash memory is shared with program data (I suppose it is), even then my sketch is that big:

```
Sketch uses 770466 bytes (58%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.
```

So if total space for program is less then 1.5 mb, then I should have over 2.5 mb of flash stoarge available for SPIFFS (if my thinking is right - but probably isn't).

In tools menu there is also "Partition Scheme" which I have set to default, since other options are

```
No OTA (Large APP)
```

and

```
Minimal SPIFFS (Large APPS with OTA)
```

which sound contrary to what I want to archive (had to put these two as code because stack woudn't let my post question otherwise).

So what is wrong here?

Comment: I have 1.0.4 ESP32 boards package and there is for example `No OTA (1MB APP/3MB SPIFFS)`

Comment: I have the same package but for WEMOS Lolin32 there is "No OTA (Large APP)". But it also doesn't work.

Comment: try `ESP32 Dev Module` for more options. default partitioning has 1.5 MB SPIFFS

Comment: Thanks, It gave me some boost in SPIFFS memory.